# Xcode 10 Mojave update can no longer find git remotes (BitBucket in my case)

Tags: ios, xcode, git, bitbucket

I was using a BitBucket git remote successfully in the Xcode 10 Beta but as soon as I updated to Mojave and to Xcode 10 I could no longer push to the remote.

When I try to add an account (BitBucket, GitHub, etc) it grays out all of the options except for Apple ID and Xcode Server and the loading spinner never stops like this:
[Grayed out account options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRlHM.png)

I seem to be able to add a remote without logging in to a BitBucket account, but am unable to push to the remote. If I go to commit my changes, the remote will not load:
[Remote(s) will not load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73MsA.png)

Remotes also do not load if I try to push local changes after local commit.

In short, I can no longer push to remotes through Xcode.

Comment: Change to your project directory via Terminal and check the output of `git remote -v`.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Hi! I'm getting the following error:   
'xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun'    
I assume this has something to do with Xcode wanting me to reinstall the command line tools when I first updated. Could this be what is causing my problem?    
Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @NimeshNeema Ok, I fixed the last error by following this solution: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254381 and I was able to add and push to remotes through Xcode after. I still can't add any accounts through Xcode (bitbucket, github, etc.) but this will suffice, all I needed was to be able to push again! Thanks for your help!